# cin.get() not working?

Tags: c++

I'm using C++ for the first time from PHP. I was playing around with some code. To my understanding `cin.get();` was suppose to stop the window from closing until I press a key, however it doesn't seem to be working because of the code before it, I don't know what the problem is. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int multiply (int x, int y);

int main ()
{
    int x;
    int y;

    cout << "Please enter two integers: ";
    cin >> x >> y;

    int total = multiply(x, y);
    cout << total;

    cin.get();
}

int multiply (int x, int y) {
    return x*y;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "stop the page closing"

Comment: @Tyler just use getch(); instead of cin.get();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a

```cpp
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n')
```

after `>> x >> y;` (or before `cin.get()`).

This flushes the buffer of `cin` and deletes the pending `\n` which is still there, because you `cin` reads x and y but also reads the last return (after y). This gets read in when you call `cin.get()`. If you flush the buffer `cin.get()` will see an empty buffer and everything is fine.

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
cin.ignore(256,'\n');
```

just before the final

```
cin.get();
```

This discards the unintentional '\n' keyed in as part of reading x and y. The page stops from closing till an additional key press as desired.

Comment: What is the number 256 for exactly? Why that number?

Answer (score 1):

It reads the newline character which is still left present in the input stream as the previous read could extract it from the stream.

See this:

```
cin >> x >> y;
```

It only reads two integers, but it doesn't read the newline character which was entered when you hit the  button.

Comment: OP's "stop the page closing" makes me thing this is a CGI thing - not going to work as OP expects